# How can I get a list of all iPhone pictures that are imported to iPhoto?

Tags: iphone, photos.app, exif

I have used iPhoto to backup my pictures from the iPhone. How can I find all the iPhone-photos without having to click on all the pictures to view the EXIF-info?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a smart album with a condition on the camera model (Camera model includes "iPhone").

[image]

It's even possible to select the front or rear camera by adding a condition on the aperture. [See this hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100913001832817) for details.

I believe iPhoto '09 has this - the picture above is in iPhoto '11 and it works great there.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a smart album and select by camera model.